# Update single package with meteorite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

Is there a way to update a single smart package with meteorite?

**Long story:**

I'm working on an app that uses a Smart package I'm maintaining. I'd like to be able to quickly make live change to the package and update the version app uses, without checking for all possible updates like when it's done with `mrt update`. I know I can use `mrt remove package` and then `mrt add package`, but it's not quite feasible as there are several dependencies. Is there a quick and easy way?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I think is using a hard package in `/packages`. You could download the package version you want from github and place it in `/packages` instead of the symlink. Meteorite will then use that version and ignore it when you do `mrt update`

Another slightly more tedious option, particularly when you want to modify the package, is to use the version attributes in your `smart.json` that specify a version or the repository:

Using a custom path:

```
packages: {
    "package-name" : {
        "path": "/home/meteordev/my-package"
    }
}
```

Versioning/using a github fork or tag (freezing the package versions that you want to)

```
packages: {
    "package-name" : {
        "git": "https://github.com/user/package.git"
        "tag" : "v0.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is it's my package on Atmosphere, which I'm heavily updating, and I'd like to be able to update version used in my project right after I update it on Atmosphere. I don't want to have the code in two places.

Comment: Does the second using smart.json help in this case? If you ran `mrt update` it should update the package. You could use `mrt update && meteor` instead of `meteor` to ensure its an easier workflow

Comment: `mrt update` is fine on itself, but it also updates all the other packages - which takes time and I want to avoid this. Pointing to a tag on github is also not a solution, since I want this to update easily. Is it possible to point to the most recent commit in Github? Ideally in a specified branch.

Comment: Yes it should be able to use the latest commit if you use `'branch':'master'` (master branch) instead of the `tag`. If you specify versions for the others they could also lock up, you could copy over from the smart.lock.